# How do I change the global font-size in Coda 2?

Tags: text-editors, coda

I've been looking for ages to find out how to set a global font-size in Coda 2. If I set the font-size to 30px in one document, as soon as I switch it goes back to the default font size.

So basically how do I change the font size of an whole project, or change the default one, like in Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it! You can change the default font and font size by going to Preferences > Editor > Editor Font

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/coding-with-coda/9781449356088/ch04.html